# postback to server executing different queries

Tags: html, jsp, post

I have a few `<div>` inside a forms, each thing inside the `div` contains a specific form.
When a user presses the submit button, I want to execute a different action based on

```
<form method="get" action="addprogramtodb.jsp">
<select name="cid"  style="display: none;">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>

<div id="1">
</div>

<div id="2">
</div>

<div id="3">
</div>

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the user presses the submit button I want the program to execute different queries based on what div it is in.... based on the div id, or somehow..

Comment: Can you be a little bit more vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the submit button a name and value the usual way.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="action1">
...
<input type="submit" name="action" value="action2">
...
<input type="submit" name="action" value="action3">
```

The pressed button is namely available as request parameter as well.

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if ("action1".equals(action)) {
    // action1 button is pressed.
} else ("action2".equals(action)) {
    // action2 button is pressed.
} else ("action3".equals(action)) {
    // action3 button is pressed.
}
```

---

You can if necessary give them a different name instead and then nullcheck each request parameter.

```
<input type="submit" name="action1" value="This is more i18n friendly">
...
<input type="submit" name="action2" value="Blah">
...
<input type="submit" name="action3" value="More blah">
```

with

```
if (request.getParameter("action1") != null) {
    // action1 button is pressed.
} else (request.getParameter("action2") != null) {
    // action2 button is pressed.
} else (request.getParameter("action3") != null) {
    // action3 button is pressed.
}
```

---

Or, if they are actually all in *their own* `<form>`, then you can also pass a hidden input along.

```
<form> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action1">
    ...
</form>
<form> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action2">
    ...
</form>
<form> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action3">
    ...
</form>
```

with the same server-side handling as in 1st example.

Comment: so I should have three submits inside each div tag? all with the same name? action? is that considered fine?

Comment: It's just to give the base idea. You can choose whatever name you want. The point is that the name/value of pressed button is available as request parameter as well. You just check for that in servlet the usual way.

Comment: I can't change the div to a form... I just want to know whether having three input with the same name in different div would be sufficient

Comment: Yes, just give the buttons a different value or a different name as suggested in 1st and 2nd example. You can check the request parameter value by the name and execute specific action accordingly.